# How can I select columns from a dataframe in a function?

Tags: r

There is a dataframe (x) with large number of columns. I want to select columns from it inside a function.

```
selectcols<-function(dat,xvar,yvar){
  t<-dat[,c(xvar,yvar)] 
}

selectcols(dat=x,xvar = "area",yvar = "y")
```

Here y and area are two columns. But this is not working. How can I fix it?

Comment: I thiink you don't need a function to select columns. Unless you want to add some criteria with which some columns will be selected. Have a look at this `df <-data.frame(a=1:5,b=6:10,c=40:44)`. `df[,c("a","c")]`

Comment: It's a part of a bigger codebase. And I need to do this inside a function.

Comment: you need to have a return statement inside the function.

Comment: This should work: `selectcols <- function(d,jx,jy) "["(d,c(jx,jy))`

Comment: @darwin not necessarily.  @maximusdooku Just end your function with `t` or `return(t) `. That should to the job.

Comment: I have used both t and <<. It's not working. I get this when I type t in the command line: [1] "area" "y"

Comment: If you really like words as function names, you might also be interested in the dplyr package, which has a `select`/`select_` function. With that package loaded, you could define `selectcols <- function(d,jx,jy) select_(d,jx,jy)`

Comment: @maximusdooku.  This [doc](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions) might help. But you are nearly there keep going.

Comment: any thoughts on my answer? it works.

Answer (score 0):

I like using dplyr for this

```
library(dplyr)
selectcols <- function(dat,xvar,yvar){
  t <- dat %>% select(matches(xvar), matches(yvar))
}

x <- data.frame(area = 1:10, y = 11:20, z = LETTERS[1:10])
selection <- selectcols(dat=x, xvar = "area", yvar = "y")
```